# UISearchDisplayController frame not show from top edge with auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've `UITableViewController` with `UISearchBar` in `headerView`.
When typing some string to search the status bar doesn't show correctly.
All delegates and outlets are in place.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Temporary fix which personally I don't like, but it still work (animation movement looks bad anyway):

```
- (void)resizeSeachBarBackground
{
    for (UIView *view in self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(subviews)])
        {
            for (UIView *view2 in view.subviews)
            {
                if ([view2 isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")])
                {
                    id UISearchBarBackground = view2;

                    if ([UISearchBarBackground respondsToSelector:@selector(frame)])
                    {
                        [UISearchBarBackground setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), 64.0)];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    if (!self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden)
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:true animated:false];

    [self resizeSeachBarBackground];
..
..
..
}
```

Comment: If your application supports only iOS8+, you should look at `UISearchController` ([WWDC2014 video - A Look Inside Presentation Controllers @ 13:38](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#228-video))

Comment: My app supports iOS 7.x and later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying, I delete the previous code, deleted the search bar and outlets and connected all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the same, Disable the auto layout inside interface builder and then enable the same and do the proper connection of auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the following line in the viewDidLoad fixed to it:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```